# What is the correct way to have an async function be an array member and await that array with Rx?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

I'm playin around with RxJS and am trying to define an array of mixed (both type- and synchrony-wise)  values and then feed that to the Rx's `from`.

However, i'd like for the observers to wait for each asynchronous value in the array and only then to move on to the next one: so, `q1` should be observed by ObserverA and observerB only after `'Three seconds have passed'` and, well, with a three-second delay.

I realize that this might be bending the language unnecessarily and also i'm probably missing something about how Rx works, but here is what I have tried.

```
import { Subject, from } from 'rxjs';

const testmain = async () =>{ 

  var subj = new Subject()
    subj.subscribe({
        next: v => console.log(`observer A: ${v}`)
    })
    subj.subscribe({
        next: v => console.log(`observer B: ${v}`)
    })



    const observable = from([
 await setTimeout(() => {return 'Three seconds have passed'}, 3000),   // am i not invoking something here or is await in the wrong place? Getting an immediate response with value [Object object]
'q1 ', 
'q23',
'error',
'condition',
 4,
 false,
 true])


    observable.subscribe(subj)
}
```

Òutput:

```
observer A: [object Object]
observer B: [object Object]
observer A: q1
observer B: q1
observer A: q23
observer B: q23
observer A: error
observer B: error
observer A: condition
observer B: condition
observer A: 4
observer B: 4
observer A: false
observer B: false
observer A: true
observer B: true
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't return a Promise so you can't use `await` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that timeout is not a promise.

```
import { Subject, from } from 'rxjs';

const testmain = async () =>{ 

  var subj = new Subject()
    subj.subscribe({
        next: v => console.log(`observer A: ${v}`)
    })
    subj.subscribe({
        next: v => console.log(`observer B: ${v}`)
    })



    const observable = from([
 await new Promise( resolver => (setTimeout(() => {resolve ('Three seconds have passed')}, 3000)),   
'q1 ', 
'q23',
'error',
'condition',
 4,
 false,
 true])


    observable.subscribe(subj)
}
```